# Build not visible in itunes connect after successfully uploaded in xcode 8

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

I have uploaded my build successfully. but does not show on iTunes.

That does not show even processing.

I have done multiple tries;

First, try:
I have changed my provisioning profile but certificates are same.

second try:

I have uploaded the same build with another provisioning profile.
versioning is same and build number is same.
 its given error

Redundant Binary:

> ERROR ITMS-4238: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '1' for train '1.4'" at SoftwareAssets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset

Third Try:
I have uploaded the third build with another provisioning profile with another build number and version number but not show on iTunes.

Please clear my doubt about uploading the build.

1.If I have changed the certificates or provisioning profile my build is uploading on the same path(already uploaded on iTunes) or not.

2.I have deleted the current certificates and recreate the certificates and upload the build with new version its possible to upload on the same path.

please suggest me.

Answer (score -3):

When you upload you build you're saving it to use it from iTunes Connect.

1) Go to https://itunesconnect.apple.com/

2) Go to Apps

3) Create a new app, complete all fields and select **the build you've done with Xcode**

4) After complete, you will send your application to be reviewed by Apple. If Apple accepts it, you can upload it to iTunes

Comment: May be you don't understand my question i have already uploaded the 1.3 version on app store and thats build is on live. when ever i have changed the build version try to upload this time the build not seen on app store after successfully upload from application loader.

Comment: If you upload a new build you have to go to My Apps in iTunes Connect, go into your app, and create another version of your app. It goes tor review again, and if accepted, into Appstore. Did you create the version of the app in iTunes Connect, inside your live app?

Comment: I have already created man and uploded successfully but not see on itunes connect. and my build no. 1.3 is already ready for sale. i have submit the another build version.

Comment: did you find any solution for your problem? @amitsrivastava